# Get value from formula cell to trigger email sending

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

I am trying to get an e-mail to be sent when the value in a cell that contains a formula goes below a certain number.

I have achieved this for various other spreadsheets that have the cell value manually entered, but for this specific one sheet where the value on the cell results from a simple SUM formula, the e-mail is not being sent. Now if I enter the value manually into the cell, the e-mail is sent right away.

Below is the code and here is a copy of my spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gnmJfkmIKHyNqLqTFK-bdOZnh2Ejkia6xo3r_3cjwkk/edit?usp=sharing

```
function CheckBasketsInventory(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var inventorySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Baskets");
  var rowIndex = e.range.getRow();
  var columnIndex = e.range.getColumn();
  var numCols = 11;
  var row = inventorySheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, numCols).getValues()[0];
  var editedInventory = row[10];
  var editedMinimum = row[8];
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  // Checking that: (1) edited cell is an inventory quantity, and (2) Inventory is below minimum
  if(editedInventory <= editedMinimum && sheetName == "Baskets" && columnIndex == 11 && rowIndex > 1) {
    var inventoryValues = inventorySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var emailBody = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < inventoryValues.length; i++) {
      var inventory = inventoryValues[i][10];
      var minimum = inventoryValues[i][8];
      if(inventory <= minimum) {
        var productName = inventoryValues[i][0] + " " + inventoryValues[i][1] + " " + inventoryValues[i][2];
        var productUnits = minimum + " " + inventoryValues[i][9];
        var messagePart1 = "Inventory for " + productName + " has gone under " + productUnits + ". ";
        var messagePart2 = "Organise purchase order. Inventory as of today is: " + inventory + " " + inventoryValues[i][9];
        var message = messagePart1.concat(messagePart2);
        var newItem = "<p>".concat(message, "</p>");
        emailBody += newItem;
      }
    }
    var emailSubject = "Low inventory alert";
    var emailAddress = "danielrzg@gmail.com";
    // Send Alert Email
    if(emailBody != "") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: emailSubject,
        htmlBody: emailBody
      });  
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions):

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling FormResponse.submit() to submit a new form response
>   does not cause the form's submit trigger to run.

This includes values edited by a Sheet Formula not triggering an `onEdit` trigger.

Comment: I tried changing the trigger to `onChange` but it still didn't work, what would be a possible solution?

Comment: It's not possible with triggers. The only solution would be saving the previous value somewhere, and run a script every x minutes to check if the value changed.

Comment: What if I transfer the formula from the spreadsheet to the script?
For example instead of having the value for the Inventory sourcing from column K which is a formula, I could have the Inventory value as: D + E + F + G + H hard coded in the script itself, which in turn IF smaller or equal to the minimum would activate the trigger on edit. Would that work?

Comment: No, the onEdit trigger can only be activated if the user changes the sheet manually.